# Json no se puede mapear a objetos error RESTEASY003145: Unable to find a MessageBodyReader of content-type application/json

Tags: java, maven

Tengo la siguiente situación: He creado dos proyectos maven, el primero un Api RestFul que retorna json, el segundo un proyecto java ejecutable que consume el Api RestFul. Cuando trabajo con los IDE (Eclipse, Netbeans) y ejecuto el segundo proyecto, desde el IDE, todo es una maravilla y funciona sin errores y todo ok. Sin embargo cuando ejecuto el jar desde linea de comandos (asi va a funcionar en producción) me presenta el error

> RESTEASY003145: Unable to find a MessageBodyReader of content-type application/json and type class com.mycompany.myapp.RespuestaDato

Para consumir el Api estoy usando el framework `Resteasy` y lo hago a través de un proxy como lo indican en la siguiente guia:

https://www.baeldung.com/resteasy-client-tutorial

Las conexiones hacia el api se levanta, el api responde de forma correcta, el cliente recibe la respuesta (lo se por que al pasarla a string e imprimirla por pantalla lo hace sin problemas), pero no la puede convertir a objeto.

la sigiente es la configuración de mi proyecto cliente

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
    <artifactId>MyApp</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0.0</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>MyApp</name>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <version.compiler.plugin>3.8.1</version.compiler.plugin>
        <version.surefire.plugin>3.0.0-M3</version.surefire.plugin>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-client</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.26.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-jackson-provider</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.26.Final</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
        <sourceDirectory>src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${version.compiler.plugin}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${maven.compiler.source}</source>
                    <target>${maven.compiler.target}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.2</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <mainClass>com.mycompay.myapp.MainClass</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>make-assembly</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M1</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

**Clase Model**

```
public class DatoModel {

    private Integer idDato;
    private String dato1;
    private String dato2;
    private String dato3;

    public DatoModel() {
    }

    public DatoModel(Integer idDato, String dato1, String dato2, String dato3) {
        this.idDato = idDato;
        this.dato1 = dato1;
        this.dato2 = dato2;
        this.dato3 = dato3;
    }

//getter y setter
}

public class RespuestaDato {

    private List<DatoModel> datos;

    public RespuestaDato() {

    }

    public RespuestaDato(List<DatoModel> datos){
        this.datos = datoss;
    }

//getter y setter
}
```

**Proxy**

```
@Path("/datos")
public interface IDatoProxyClient {

    @GET
    @Path("/datos")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    RespuestaDato obtenerDatos();
}
```

**Cliente**

```
ResteasyClient client = new ResteasyClientBuilder().build();
ResteasyWebTarget target = client.target(UriBuilder.fromPath("http://localhost:8080/MyApiRest/rest"));

IDatoProxyClient proxyClient = target.proxy(IDatoProxyClient.class);
RespuestaDato respuesta = proxyClient.obtenerDatos(); //acá se genera el error
```

he buscado a que pueda deberse y no he encontrado solución, Agradezco de su ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

Puede ser que te esté faltando una librería que sepa como convertir de objetos a JSON y de JSON a objetos y que no lo tengas en tu classpath.

Intenta agregar esta dependencia (Hay que revisar si la versión es la que necesitas)

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
    <artifactId>resteasy-jackson-provider</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.4.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por contestar @Alejandro-Giordi sin embargo esa dependencia ya esta en el `pom`

Comment: ¿Y estas generando un jar solamente? ¿Como desplegás esto? Me suena a que no está encontrando esa dependencia que te digo. No se está dando cuenta de como hacer el marshalling y el unmarshalling

Comment: Si, es un jar ejecutable, tiene su clase main, y debe conectarse con el recurso, hacer un proceso y ya. Pues a mi que me parece lo mismo pero ya he borrado el target, el .m2 y sigue igual.

Comment: ¿Usas maven para generar el jar? ¿Haces mvn package y luego ejecutas el jar desde linea de comandos?

Comment: Buenas noches,  @alejandro-giorgi la respuesta es si, es un archivo jar para ejecutar, sin embargo comento que ya funciono, algo debio estar pegado o en cache, primero subi las versiones de las librerias a 4.0 y cambie el plugin de assembly por uno de copia de dependencias y empezo a funcionar, despues volvi a bajar las librerias a la version 3.0.26 y siguio funcionando de forma correcta. Lo que lo haya solucionado no lo sabria decir.